# Firebase - Filtering Query Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a group of comments for different blog posts.

The problem now is every comment displays on every blog post.

Im calling the data with

```
myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comments");
```

Which returns all comments.

This is the data JSON

```
    {
  "comments" : {
    "-KgnRe9d5s471yDWVYBk" : {
      "_id" : "56e35e39106a750e008c33b5",
      "_blogID" : "56ba5f6a894eeb0e008c86c0",
      "commentKey" : "-KgnRe9d5s471yDWVYBk",          
      "detail" : "test comment",
      "user" : "john",
      "votes" : 0
    }
```

Id like to filter all comments by "_blogID"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Query` like this: `Query query = myref.child(commentKey).orderByChild("_blogID");`

Comment: But all the IDs (eg. KgnRe9d5s471yDWVYBk) are unique. How do i query all children then filter by _blogID ?

Comment: Yes, all the keys are unique but when you use the `push()` method, to generate those unique kesy, is the moment in which you can get those keys like this: `myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comments").push();` and after that `String commentKey = myref.getKey()`. Than you can use commentKey in your `query`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there no way to include all keys and search by the blogID?

Comment: If you want to search a comment, you can use the `equalTo()` method. In your particular case, you can use something like this: `myref.child(commentKey).orderByChild("_blogID").equalsTo("56ba5f6a894eeb0e008c86c0");`